# Problem with upstart sessions: unable to granpt:Exec format error

Tags: kde, upstart, arm, chromebook, chromeos

I have a very specific problem. I have installed an arm ubuntu 13.10 on chromebook with original chromebooks linux kernel.

And I got the strange errors in ~/.xsession-errors which prevents me to start the kde desktop:

```
init: Failed to spawn logrotate pre-start process: unable to granpt: Exec format error
...
```

granpt? What does it mean? I discovered that the string "unable to granpt" is defined in init binary.

Also I have found that those errors caused by /etc/X11/Xsession.d/00upstart, so when I remove it, the kde starts normally, but lacks some features like virtual terminal, etc. 
All ubuntu scripts are orginal and not modified. Looks like it is problem with some security restrictions in chromebook kernel, but I can't understand how those sessions runs and how I can debug it?

Does anyone are close familiar with upstart to help me?

Answer (score 0):

I did have the same error message but with the mysql service :

```
init: Failed to spawn mysql pre-start process: unable to granpt: No such file or directory
```

It seems that it is caused by the /dev/pts not being mounted.

In my case mounting /dev/pts with that command fixed the problem :

```
mount devpts /dev/pts -t devpts
```

Yet I don't have any expertise to tell why /dev/pts is not mounted nor why it causes some service not being able to be started by upstart